# How to list classpath for tests in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, classpath

When I try running `gradle test`, I get the following output:

```
$ gradle test
:ro:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:ro:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:ro:classes UP-TO-DATE
:ro:jar
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test

ro.idea.ToggleTest > testIsAd FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at ToggleTest.java:13
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at ToggleTest.java:13

ro.idea.ToggleTest > testToggle FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at ToggleTest.java:13

2 tests completed, 2 failed
:test FAILED
```

So I want to check my classpath to see whether my classpath is wrong or not.

**My question is:** How can I list the classpath at `test` time with a Gradle task?

Answer (score 38):

You can list test runtime dependencies with:

```
gradle dependencies --configuration=testRuntime
```

Or, if you want to see the actual files:

```
task printClasspath {
    doLast {
        configurations.testRuntime.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this include dependencies declared with `testCompile` / `testImplementation` ?

Comment: @BradMace Use `testRuntimeClasspath` to get it to include `testImplementation`

Comment: I get error "Could not get unknown property 'testRuntime' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer."

Answer (score 3):

Also, to list the classpath for the main (non-test) application run use:

```
run << {
    doLast {
        configurations.runtime.each { println it }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me (Gradle 6.3, Kotlin DSL):

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    this.classpath.forEach { println(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using a Gradle wrapper, you can use the following.

```
./gradlew dependencies --configuration=testRuntimeClasspath
```

It will list the dependencies as available to your tests.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me (in Gradle 5.6)

```
task printTestClasspath.doLast {
  println(sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.asPath)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding solution of Peter Niederwieser, if you want to print from all possible configurations (using the simple loop) and ignoring possible errors:

```
task printClasspath {
    doLast {
        configurations.each { Configuration configuration ->
            try {
                println configuration
                configuration.each { println it }
            } catch (Exception e){
                println "Error getting details of $configuration"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gradle 7.3.3. and this worked for me:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  println("Test classpath")
  sourceSets.test.get().runtimeClasspath.forEach { println(it) }
}
```